# AWS EC2のSDKによるコピー

Tags: aws, amazon-ec2

お世話になっております。

AWSのSDK for javaを利用して、EC2のインスタンスコピーを行いたいのですが、
失敗してしまいます。

具体的には、下記のようなエラーが返ってきます。
「You do not have permission to access the storage of this ami 」

EC2の許可がないようなのですが、そのような設定はどこで行うのでしょうか。

ソースコードは下記サイト様を参照しております。
http://qiita.com/uzresk/items/c8c0f0ab0306780b2966

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決いたしました。

AMI IDの指定が間違えていただけでした。
失礼いたしました。